# jQuery FullCalendar plain looks and undefined in title

Tags: jquery, html, css, model-view-controller, fullcalendar

so I'm trying to implement FullCalendar on MVC 5 Web Application I've been working on lately, but I keep bumping my head into a wall.
At first I had problem even rendering its view on site, and I solved it but now I'm having problem with looks and functions.
[THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nvh86.png)

I used demo code for setting it up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link href="~/Scripts/lib/cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/fullcalendar.print.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                theme: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
                },

                navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                events: [
                    {
                        title: 'All Day Event',
                        start: '2017-05-01'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Long Event',
                        start: '2017-05-07',
                        end: '2017-05-10'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 999,
                        title: 'Repeating Event',
                        start: '2017-05-09T16:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 999,
                        title: 'Repeating Event',
                        start: '2017-05-16T16:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Conference',
                        start: '2017-05-11',
                        end: '2017-05-13'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Meeting',
                        start: '2017-05-12T10:30:00',
                        end: '2017-05-12T12:30:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Lunch',
                        start: '2017-05-12T12:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Meeting',
                        start: '2017-05-12T14:30:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Happy Hour',
                        start: '2017-05-12T17:30:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Dinner',
                        start: '2017-05-12T20:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Birthday Party',
                        start: '2017-05-13T07:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Click for Google',
                        url: 'http://google.com/',
                        start: '2017-05-28'
                    }
                ]
            });

        });

    </script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 40px 10px;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        #calendar {
            max-width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
     <div id='calendar'></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Included bundles:

```
   //Calendar css file
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/fullcalendarcss").Include(
                 "~/Content/themes/jquery.ui.all.css",
                 "~/Content/fullcalendar.css"));

        //Calendar Script file

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/fullcalendarjs").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/fullcalendar.min.js"));
```

Rendered styles (in head of _layout):

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/fullcalendarcss")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

And scripts (bottom of body):

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fullcalendarjs")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Using latest version installed via Package Manager on Visual Studio.

P.S. I create calendar as partial view, and I'm rendering it on Index via:

```
@Html.Partial("Date")
```

What am I missing here?

Console log: [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3YT3.png)

Comment: check your console, any errors?

Comment: Yeah actually alot, I updated post with screenshot.

Comment: You show some sample code, with the `<script>` references hard-coded, and then some bundle definitions. It's not clear how these two things are related? Are you saying the first one is just a demo you found, and you didn't actually use that? You should show _your_ actual code, not something you based it on. If all that's being rendered to _your_ page is what's in the bundles, then very obviously you've forgotten to include moment.js. Also I would guess that is at the root of the error with the "getEventTimeText" method you're getting - that's a time-related function which might rely on moment.

Comment: if you have included all the scripts and css in bundle and rendering inside your page then why your again adding them ?check your html page

Comment: No, no, I used that, it is code from my projects partial view for calendar, and I grabbed that code from demo version of fullcalendar. As I googled some fix for that I also saw it should be added as bundles so I included fullcalendar files into bundles and as classic scripts.

Comment: @this.girish I couldnt render view  at all till I added scripts inside head of partial view.

Comment: if you are adding bundles then remove your hard coded <script> and <link> references, make sure you added them only once, after removing them check path of all your  js and css in bundle,if they are correct clean your project rebuild and run

Comment: "it is code from my projects partial view for calendar". Why has a partial view got a fresh `<html>`, `<doctype>` etc declaration in it? You're trying to declare a page within a page. You need to get a better understanding of how a HTML document is structured. Strip out all the tags that are already in your layout and index pages (doctype, html, head, body and any others). Lastly, even without that problem, you're probably creating havoc by including some of the files as bundles _and_ as `<script>` tags. Each script/CSS file should be included _once_ in the whole page.